# How to generate rooms and connections between them from the set room list (given room sizes) on the 2D table?

Tags: java, arrays, random, generator

I'm trying to implement a dungeon generator in my small Java project (text roguelike - moving from start to exit with random events on the map) but there is one problem - I'm just starting with Java and I don't know a lot about "proper" coding, thus having problems with the generating the map; map is a 2D array (ex. 50x50 tiles) where you move your character between rooms connected with multiple corridors.

I was considering a few options how to make it:

- make a list of set rooms which then they would appear in the specific places on the array (dividing 50x50 array to 5x5 tiles and then from the first 4x4 tile choose one point there would be the left upper corner of the room - the smallest room I want to make 2x2)
- to generate the map by going each column while generating a few playable tiles and the next column would add another playable tiles next to the existing ones + after a few iterations making corridors but it sounds more complicated
- making corridors by checking if 2 tiles (that are rooms) are on the same level (vertical or horizontal) and then swapping tiles from "wall" to "playable" ones (it's a text game so from "#" to ".")

Does it sound viable or should I look for some other solution? Or is it too complicated/nearly impossible and there is a way simpler way of doing it?

```
# # # # # # #
# # . . . # #
# # . # . E #
# # . . . # #
# # . # . # #
# H . . . # #
# # # # # # #
```

"H" is a hero, "E" is exit, "#" are walls and "." playable tiles (where you can move by an input - up/down/left/right)

Comment: Java would be fine. Use an array in a class called Board, and write a method to print it like in your picture. Download an IDE like Intellij. They have a free version. The biggest hurdle is learning a new language, and working alone. You might look for a group of like minded individuals either online or in person doing similar things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to java and android too and I'd have to say it sounds fairly complicated but not impossible. If you haven't done so already, I'd highly recommend taking an online course. www.udemy.com is where I took one for Android Nougat and have just signed up for another designed for Q.

I'd imagine doing it in a way that calls a random number to select which wall you'll leave through, another to pick where on the wall the exit is, then create a method to call that generates a random room to the maximum parameters you set with another random number to select where on the new room you connect your corridor to. I could be designed in a way that the new rooms aren't generated until the user is within... say, 2 points of the exit rather than generating the map ahead of time.

I would say that knowing 'proper' coding would be essential to complete this though. Not knowing how much you know/don't know, it would be too much to put into this post I think.

Good luck though.